# what is the logic behind percentile_cont()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What is the logic behind percentile_cont()

It is quite easy to understand percentile_cont(0.5) which is the median

But what about percentile_cont(0.9)?

Given value 22, 22, 25, 25, 28

Thanks

r

Comment: I think it's more mathematical question... Read about percentiles, it's part of statistics.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for `percentile_cont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql) in SQL Server, the numeric value you are passing directly to the function represents:

> The percentile to compute. The value must range between 0.0 and 1.0.

So if you were to use `percentile_cont(0.9)` you would be targeting the 90th percentile over a list of numeric values, possibly including some sort of partition.  The median may have some special meaning in your head as the data point which has an equal number of points both ahead and behind it, but the median is also just the 50th percentile.  As a side note, if the data set has an even number of points, the median is often taken as being the average of the middle two points.